# Unable to focus on a text field after routing in AngularJS app

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am working with an AngularJS application where I want to place the cursor/focus on a particular
text box when route to that page. But after trying many times with setFocus() method of JavaScript, autofocus of HTML and other workarounds this seem not to work. What is happening is that the focus/cursor always lands/returns on the first text box on the page after a brief focus on the required text box. I am unable to determine what is causing this behavior.

I also tried to work with eventListeners but in vain. What I did was that on focus on the first text box, I set the focus on the required text box. But it does not work.

This is the page on which I am trying to achieve this functionality:

HTML:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">
        <input type="number" class="form-control" id="dN1" name="dN1" ng-model="ob.dt" title="{{ title }}" ng-maxlength="4"  />
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-md-20 col-md-offset-14">
        <input type="text" capitalize trim-spaces class="form-control" id="ifp" name="ifp" ng-model="ob.ifp" />
    </div>
</div>
```

I want the focus to come to text box with 'ifp' id when the page loads initially or even if it comes after 
a route.

On the JS side, in the controller I have already tried these, but they dont seem to work:

```
window.onload = function setFocus() {
    var el = document.getElementById('ifp');
    if (el) {
      el.focus();
    }
  }

  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    var ifp = $window.document.getElementById('ifp');
    ifp.focus();
  }, false);

  $scope.putFocus = function(){
    $window.document.getElementById('ifp').focus();
  }
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this hack:

```
$scope.putFocus = function(){
   $timeout(function(){
       $window.document.getElementById('ifp').focus();
  },0)
  }

$scope.putFocus();
```

**You can also use `autofocus` attribute in the element itself to put focus**

```
<input autoFocus />
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. There's a minor typo in the case when you call the function. Please fix it so that others can benefit.
Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

use **ng-init** instead of **DOMContentLoaded**
---------HTML----------

```
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-md-20 col-md-offset-14">
        <input type="text" capitalize trim-spaces class="form-control" id="ifp" name="ifp" ng-model="ob.ifp" ng-init="putFocus()"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

---------Controller -------

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    //var ifp = $window.document.getElementById('ifp');
    //ifp.focus();
}, false);
```